# TP-LINK Archer d50 modem is blocking FTP access to a specific website

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ftp, connection

I tried sharing internet from my smartphone and it worked on my PC.
When I switched to modem connection, I can log in FTP server but it not shows me directories.

I tried also forwarding port 20 and 21 on my router, but I'm not sure it is right.
Someone can tell me what put in these fields?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ74e.png)

I've also tried both active and passive mode, but nothing changed.
The website is www.binini.it, I've tried a lot of client such as FileZilla, CoreFtp and Cyberduck. I noticed that with net2ftp it works.

Here's the FileZilla traceback.

```
Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/**hidden**" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/**hidden**" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

With ftp.exe I can log in but I got stacked after "quote pasv". Terminal answer me with "connection closed from remote host".

This is the complete debug log:

```
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    USER w8km01a130
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   331 Password required for w8km01a130.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    PASS **********
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   230 User logged in.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
Command:    SYST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   215 Windows_NT
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 7
Command:    FEAT
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Response:    LANG EN*
Response:    UTF8
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT C;P;
Response:    CCC
Response:    HOST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:   211 END
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 9
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 9
Status: Logged in
Trace:  Measured latency of 62 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   257 "/w8km01a130" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    TYPE I
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CRealControlSocket::OnClose(106)
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Status: Disconnected from server
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    USER w8km01a130
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   331 Password required for w8km01a130.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    PASS **********
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   230 User logged in.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 9
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 9
Status: Logged in
Trace:  Measured latency of 81 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   257 "/w8km01a130" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    TYPE I
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CRealControlSocket::OnClose(106)
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
```

This is the trace back with my phone shared connection:

```
    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    USER w8km01a130
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   331 Password required for w8km01a130.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Command:    PASS **********
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   230 User logged in.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
Command:    SYST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   215 Windows_NT
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 7
Command:    FEAT
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    LANG EN*
Response:    UTF8
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT C;P;
Response:    CCC
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    HOST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:   211 END
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 9
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 9
Status: Logged in
Trace:  Measured latency of 276 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   257 "/w8km01a130" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    TYPE I
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (66,71,190,20,195,87).
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Destination IP of data connection does not match peer IP of control connection. Not binding source address of data connection.
Command:    LIST
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnClose(0)
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 3
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 4
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Command:    MDTM Main.Master
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   213 20170703210504
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Status: Timezone offset of server is 7200 seconds.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Status: Directory listing of "/w8km01a130" successful
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

Comment: You do not want to forward ports on your router - that is related to you hosting a server.

Comment: So, what I have to do for allowing me to access ftp and "bypass" router?

Comment: I've tried both passive and active mode

Comment: The router is NATing between your local network and the internet. To access servers on the internet, you shouldn't need to do anything. FTP is different, because in 'active' mode, the server will try to connect back to you. For this to work, you need to forward ports. Hence FTP active mode is generally considered 'broken' - it contradicts the typical client/server model.

Comment: Does your modem/router have any built-in firewall functionality that may be blocking one or more of the control or data ports for FTP...

Comment: @Attie, thanks for explanation, so what should I do? As I said, the website I'm tring accessing to is the only wich give me problem. Other website works.

Comment: @FilippoScaramuzza: could you add some more details, i.e. what site is the problem, which client you use and maybe debug information from the client (many offer a trace of the connection)?

Comment: @FilippoScaramuzza: could you add even more information? Especially the exact reply to the PASV command would be interesting. Maybe increase the log level so you get these information.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: you mean by using command line? Something like ftp.exe?

Comment: @FilippoScaramuzza: no, I mean that filezilla should provide more detailed  information, see http://ccm.net/faq/28699-filezilla-display-the-debug-menu

Comment: Your control connection gets disconnected as soon as the `PASV` command is issued. This could be a bug on the server or an issue with your (router) firewall's FTP NAT helper. Out of curiosity: Could you provide the entire log for listing a directory when connected with your phone?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich as you asked I've put the complete reply of FileZilla

Comment: @FilippoScaramuzza: Thanks. See my new response based on this detailed logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the successful trace:

> Status: Connecting to 209.227.193.130:21...
>   ...
>   Command:    PASV
>   Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (66,71,190,20,195,87).
>   ...
>   Trace:  Destination IP of data connection does not match peer IP of control connection....

The response to the passive command is saying, that the server should be connected at 66.71.190.20 port 50007 (195*256+87) for the data connection. Note that this IP address is different from the address of the server you've connected to. While in theory the original FTP protocol supports this mode of operation where the server for the control connection is different from the server for the data connection it is very uncommon and is more likely caused by a misconfiguration at the server end. Based on tracepath I would say that this is actually a different address on the same server.

And this is probably the reason the transfer fails. At the log over your TP-Link router you find the following reaction to the PASV command:

> Command:    PASV
>   Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted

I would interpret this as the FTP helper at the router aborted the FTP connection because the PASV command resulted in an unexpected response, in that the IP inside PASV which should be used for the data connection did not match the IP of the control connection.

This also explains why the problems only happen with this specific server, because all the other servers don't show this unusual behavior.

But, in case this is really just a different address on the same server you might try to FTP connect to 66.71.190.20 instead of 209.227.193.130. Hopefully the first one will succeed since IP in control connection and PASV response are the same then.

Comment: The IP octets aren’t switched around, but yeah. The FTP server probably has multiple IP addresses and just goes with the primary one.

Comment: @DanielB: you are right with the IP - I've fixed this. And yes, this might be the same host based on tracepath.

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much @SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 0):

FTP is just a nightmarish protocol because it uses dynamic ports and exchange of the relevant port numbers is done at the application layer. This means often helpers are involved in firewalls or NAT routers or at the ISP and mobile provider (for carrier grade NAT) which might work or might not work.

Problems are especially use of FTPS (i.e. encrypted FTP) where the helper application cannot get the port numbers because the traffic is encrypted. Problem are also with newer commandos which were added to support IPv6 but which are often used without IPv6 too (i.e. EPRT, EPSV instead of PORT and PASV).

In short: try to use SFTP instead of FTP/FTPS. SFTP is file transfer on top of SSH, is more secure and has none of the problems of FTP(S) regarding dynamic ports. Of course, the server needs to support it.

Comment: It seems server doesn't support SFTP, thank you anyway..